# Fertilizing plumerias with homemade fertilizer

Tags: plant-care

Wondering if there is a combination of commonly found household items , e.eg. Food , oil, whatever, that can be used to fertilize plumerias

Comment: In general, if you doesn't have many (really many) plants, it is not practical to create most fertilizers. Food is often salty (no good for most of plants). For preparation items, it will be mostly vegetables, so low density). You can still find organic fertilizers (or just the correct soil type).

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Fertilisers are made with various formulations, the principal ones being Nitrogen, Phosphorus and Potassium, shown as NPK on containers of fertiliser. Plumeria (if you'd like to try to get it to flower) require a lot of phosphorus, and not too much nitrogen if they are growing in pots. Trying to get the formula right using, for instance, home made compost tea is very difficult, and certainly oils and foodstuffs will do nothing at all other than maybe kill your plant. Further information here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/plumeria/how-to-fertilize-plumeria.htm